# Why and when does this char * change values?

Tags: c++

Observe the following code.  The reason I am juggling from `std::string` to c-style string and back to `std::string` is because `bmd2create` is part of a C Binding API and it must take a c-style string.  Otherwise I am using `std::string` whenever possible.

### OtherFile.h

```
void bmd2create(const char * filename) {
  std::string sFileName (filename);

  // do things with sFileName

  std::ostringstream ostr;
  ostr << "\t(in)  filename       = " << filename << "\n";
  logger.log(Logger::LogLevel::LOG_DEBUG, ostr.str());
}
```

### Main.cpp

```
const char * filename = std::string(filepath + "dataset1.out").c_str();

// *filename is 46 '.'

bmd2create(filename);

// *filename is now 0 '\0'
```

### The question

Where and why is the filename pointer being moved?  And what is the best way to move it back to the start of the string?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap this `bmd2create` into something that takes `std::string const&`?

Comment: "Where and why is the filename pointer being moved?" What do you mean when you say "moved"? The internal data (accessible with str.data()) is moved when the string grows beyond it's str.capacity().

Comment: @Kay: Or when the string is destroyed, which is happening here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is particularly useless:

```
const char * filename = std::string(filepath + "dataset1.out").c_str();
```

You create a temporary `std::string`, and then get a pointer to its content with `c_str()`.  The temporary variable gets cleaned up at the end of the full-expression, before the next line executes.  At that point the pointer is going nowhere.  Using it is undefined behavior.

The reason you think the pointer is ok before the call to `bmd2create` is that the memory pointed to hasn't been overwritten yet.  But it is no longer owned by the string, so any future allocation can replace it with a new object.

Correct code would be:

```
std::string filename = std::string(filepath) + "dataset1.out";
bmd2create(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: Oh wow.  I mixed this up with the array syntax you sometimes see with `new`, ie `const char * filename = new char[20]`  I guess if you don't have the `new` then you're going to have huge problems.  Unfortunately I seem to love shooting myself in the foot with C++... or blowing my whole leg off.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: Unlike `new`, `malloc`, `strdup`, etc, `std::string` comes with a destructor that frees the memory automatically.  That's usually considered a good thing, because it prevents a leak when you forget to free it.  But you do still have to think about object lifetime.